# Realtime chart in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, charts, data-visualization, real-time-data

I am building a realtime dashboard , Backend is ready (it's done in node js express and socket.io ) used socket.io for sending data . Frontend is done in react using socket.io client.

Everything is working fine the data is coming at the speed I want ( I am having approx 200 data per second )
But when I try to visualise it in chart it's Speed gradually decrease. I think chart isn't able to handle that .

Charts I tried

1. Apex charts
2. Recharts
   3 . React-charts.js

Ps:- [ Currently I am using use effect so that it rerender every time new data enters ]

Can you suggest any method or any other charts or the reason for this issue .

Help is much appreciated

Comment: You can use pagination or apply some optimizations (memoization). I think the library wont affect it too much,

Comment: I tried @Roshomon but it didn't helped me much .If you have done anything similar should I show you my code ?